# Azure data factory data lake analytics linked service provisioning failed

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am creating pipeline using azure data lake factory. Pipeline has one data lake analytics U-SQL activity. This used to work fine but stopped working stating i need refresh credential tokens.

When I autorize again and deploy I get error saying "Provisioning failed. Internal server error. Request id :....".

```
{
"name": "DataLakeAnalyticsLinkedService",
"properties": {
    "description": "",
    "hubName": "datafactory_hub",
    "type": "AzureDataLakeAnalytics",
    "typeProperties": {
        "accountName": "datalakeanlytics",
        "authorization": "**********",
        "sessionId": "**********",
        "subscriptionId": "......",
        "resourceGroupName": "DataLake"
    }
}
```

}

I have tried restarting browser session, creating new service it still fails.

Is there anything else am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response.

I have checked with the Azure Data Factory team and Data Factory had issues with the ADL Analytics 3 days back which is now fixed. Could you please delete the existing ADL Analytics linked service and create again, which should work?

Sorry for the inconvenience, and if you have any questions, feel free to let me know or raise a support ticket.

Xiaoyong Zhu from Azure Data Lake Team

Answer (score 0):

I guess the authentication token is expired somehow, and I guess you can update the credential in the Data Factory UI. You can refer to this article (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/creating-big-data-pipelines-using-azure-data-lake-and-azure-data-factory/) for more information.

We will investigate why the token got expired and will update this thread later.

Thanks,

Xiaoyong Zhu from Azure Data Lake Team

Comment: I have tried reauthicate multiple time, in different browsers still get same error.

Comment: is it possible to get more information on error using requested provided in error message?

Comment: I have never encountered this problem before, but let me follow up with the team to see if they have more thoughts here. You can also reach me at xiaoyzhu at microsoft dot com.